Routing for spring boot and angular app in the same container
My web app has Angular and Spring Boot running the same same container. How can I forward some URLs to index.html, which is the real resource for a single page Angular app?
For example, my Angular route
    export const routes: Routes = [
        { path: '', redirectTo: '/license', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'licenses', component: LicensesComponent },
        { path: 'license', component: LicenseComponent }
        ];

When a user access http://localhost/license, Standalone Angular app will actually display index.html, and everything works fine. But if i deploy this angular app in the same container as Spring Boot app, the same URL will go to a RestController which serves /license. My Augular app does not work anymore.
What should I do to solve this conflict?

what does that mean deploy angular app in the same container? Do you mean deploy to the same server? How exactly do you deploy your Angular app - do you build it (with npm build) and deploy static files or you let it run on localhost:4200?

if you are talking about docker containers in that case that docker container would be same as deploying to a server - I am sure there are plenty of tutorials but one simple way: 1. build (npm build)and copy your static angular files to the server 2. set up nginx to route requests to that index.html file from angular static files 3. start spring boot app on localhost:8080. 4. Your angular app can communicate with spring boot via REST calls

Container means server, such tomcat
